# Would I lose data if I change a column from varbinary(8000) to varbinary(max)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any data loss if a table is being altered to change an existing column from varbinary(8000) to varbinary(MAX)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't lose data.

SQL Server will do an in place conversion, as a transaction. This means if anything fails, it will rollback.

Note, this is more than a simple metadata change so it may take some time because data has to be moved around

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just metadata? However varbinary(8000) is stored, varbinary(max) can store it in the exact same format, so I can't see why it'd need to make any physical changes. I'm not sure though - haven't tested.

Comment: varbinary(max) likely is not stored in the same format - it is stored outside the rows. I believe it is clearly documented. varbinary(8000) stores in the row, varbinary(max) out of the row.

Comment: Sorry @TomTom but that's not correct. Varbinary(MAX) and varbinary(8000) can both be stored in-row as well as out-of-row. Image (the classic varbinary(MAX)) type on the other hand, is always stored out of row.

Comment: @TomTom You can read about how both the varbinary(8000) and varbinary(MAX) will store it in row, or overflow using a BLOB INLINE ROOT structure for too large values in [What is the size of the LOB pointer for MAX types](http://improve.dk/what-is-the-size-of-the-lob-pointer-for-max-types-like-varchar-varbinary-etc/). Or if you want to look at source, feel free to look at the complex column handling for types 2 & 4 in [OrcaMDF's Record source](https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF/blob/master/src/OrcaMDF.Core/Engine/Records/Record.cs)

Comment: @TomTom. It is controlled by sp_tableoption http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530(v=sql.105).aspx The "old" setting is deprecated which could have made in more than a metadata change. Otherwise, upto 8000 is "in row" unless set off with the new setting. I haven't looked at this forever BTW hence my vagueness above